# My Calculations are off when Creating a BMI Calculator

Tags: java, android-fragments, math, android-studio, calculator

Problem: My Calculations are off when I compared the results on my app to the bmi website. THank you so much in advance, also my math is really bad so I apologize in advance.

Here are the results that my app is giving me:

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=8bd04d4

Here  are the results based of the BMI Website NIH

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=86d4458

BMIFRAG.java

```
       public class BmiFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener 
       {

       Button BmiButton;

      public static EditText heightFT;
      public static EditText heightIn;
      public static EditText weightIn;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       }

       @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


       View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bmi, container, 
       false);
       BmiButton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.CalculateBmi);
       BmiButton.setOnClickListener(this);
       return myView;
  }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.CalculateBmi:







                  weightIn = (EditText) 
                 getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ETtweight);

                 heightIn = (EditText)
                 getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ETHeightIn);

                 heightFT = (EditText) 
                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ETHeightFT);

                final TextView tv4 = (TextView) 
               getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TFDisplayBmi);


              String getWeightIN = weightIn.getText().toString();




            String  getHeightIN = heightIn.getText().toString();

            String getHeightFT = heightFT.getText().toString();



            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getWeightIN)) {



                weightIn.setError("Please enter your weight");
                weightIn.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getHeightIN)) {
                heightIn.setError("Please enter your height in Inches");
                heightIn.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getHeightFT)) {
                heightFT.setError("Please enter your height in Feet");
                heightFT.requestFocus();
                return;
            }


            else {

                float weight = Float.parseFloat(getWeightIN );

                float heightIN = Float.parseFloat(getHeightIN) ;
                float heightFT = Float.parseFloat(getHeightFT) ;

                float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight,heightIN,heightFT);

                String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

                   tv4.setText(String.valueOf(bmiValue + "-" + 
                 bmiInterpretation));


              }



               break;

           }
       }


      private float calculateBMI(float weight, float heightIN, float v) {



        float bmi= (float) (weight/ (heightIN*v)*4.88);

        float total= Math.round(bmi);



        return  total;
      }


           private String interpretBMI(float bmiValue) {

           if (bmiValue < 16) {
           return "Severely underweight";
          } else if (bmiValue < 18.5) {

             return "Underweight";
         } else if (bmiValue < 25) {

           return "Normal";
        } else if (bmiValue < 30) {

         return "Overweight";
        } else {
          return "Obese";


       }


      }


        @Override
         public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
          public void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();

            }

             @Override
              public void onDetach() {
             super.onDetach();
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct formula `float bmi= (float) (weight/ (heightIN*v)*4.88);`

Comment: I believe that it's right , I may be wrong like I said my math sucks. I attempted which counts for something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the same formula. Try this:

```
float bmi = weight * 703f / (float)Math.pow(heightIN+12f*v,2);
```

The formula above can be found [here](http://www.whathealth.com/bmi/formula.html).

I hope it helps.

Comment: ya man that solved it thanks again for taking the time and helping me out

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with your app!